# Using Match pattern in powershell to replace data

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, powershell-2.0

```
$Gateway = "192.168.122.1"
$Ip = "172.18.66.34"
```

My goal is to get the output as below.

```
172.18.66.1
```

1st 3 octet of $IP and 4th octet of $Gateway....combination of both...

I tried below but its not working any other logic to achieve this

```
$Gateway -match "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(?<content>)"
$fourth = $matches['content']
$mgmt = "172.18.47.19"
$mgmt -match "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(?<content>.*)"
$new = $matches['content']
$mgmt.replace($new,$fourth)
```

Comment: `$IP` is never used. Samples should only include necessary code.

Comment: One liner..$Ip.Split('.')|select -Index (0..2)| & {$ofs='.';"$input"}|select @{name="ModifiedIp";expression={$_+".
"+$Gateway.Split('.')[3]}}

Comment: I am using powershell 2.0.... and we can't use split method... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Primitive, but does the job

```
($Ip -split "\.")[0],($Ip -split "\.")[1],($Ip -split "\.")[2],($Gateway -split "\.")[-1] -join "."

172.18.66.1
```

works on powershell 2

is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to fill in a pattern in the "content"-caturing group.

Try this:

```
$Gateway -match "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(?<content>\d{1,3})"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not regex but this is a super reason to introduce you to the type `[ipaddress]`

```
$Gateway = "192.168.122.1"
$Ip = "172.18.66.34"

(([ipaddress]$Ip).GetAddressBytes()[0..2] + ([ipaddress]$Gateway).GetAddressBytes()[-1]) -join "."
```

We use the method `.GetAddressBytes()` to break out the octets and then just use array notation, concatenation and a simple `-join` to reform the address to your standard.